# Can an immediate watcher fire before its parent component mounts in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, events, hook, watch

I just can't find an explicit answer for this online. My experiments show that watchers first fire after the `mounted` hook, but I need some assurance that this is always the case, though I can't find it.

I have a parent component that is waiting for an event from a child component.

The child component emits this event from a watcher with the `immediate` option enabled.

So I need to know, can the child component in any case send this event to the parent before the parent is mounted?

Comment: `watcher` will fire when what u watch is change..

Comment: Yes this is possible, since the parent component will mount after all its child components are mounted (https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f). So just emit the event in the created hook in the child component.

Comment: @LukeHol, no how would that help, I need to fire the event on that watcher. I just need to know if the watcher can fire before the parent is mounted. From your link it seems possible... I guess? Since the child is mounted first, an the parent after that... but I don't know where in this diagram the watchers start firing.

Comment: Passing `immediate: true` as an attribute to the watcher, the watcher will be called on component creation. So that is guarantied to be run before the parent mounts.

Comment: I just tested this in a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-8ecbl. Take a look at the console output